# MapView onCLick Event Listener

Tags: android, android-mapview

So I've been trying to detect click events to a `MapView` in order to start a method with the click.

Trying any variation of standard `onClickListener` or `onTouch` were no good.

I do not want to add an overlay of to "catch" clicks on a certain part of the map.
I want the map to continue to be responsive to drag,zooms, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use onTouch method along with GestureDetector and use singleTaPconfirmed() and leave others.

Comment: SInce MapView implementation uses Surface it captures all touch events. As I wrote standard onTouch won't work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So, apparently the solution is quite simple.
I guess it was added in one of the last support libs.
GoogleMap now supports onMapClick.

```
mMapView.getMap().setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0)
                    {
                        android.util.Log.i("onMapClick", "Horray!");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple but useful solution! :)

Comment: Simple but works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

In the new version of Google Play services, you should call the method after the map is ready, at the `onMapReady(GoogleMap map);` callback.

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0)
        {
            android.util.Log.i("onMapClick", "Horray!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MapView  implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
       println("click marker");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution in *Kotlin*

**Simple Map onClick method:**

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Map Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

**Marker onClick method:**

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Marker Title: ${marker.title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        false
    }
```